# RelationShip error on EF code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, inheritance

I have a curiously problem with this program structure and EF 6.

```
public abstract class Operand
{
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Formula : Operand
{
    public Operand Operand1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Operand Operand2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String Operator
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public override int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class OperandValue<T> : Operand
{
    public T Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public override int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class OperandInt : OperandValue<int>
{
}

public class ModelEntity : DbContext
{
    public ModelEntity()
        : base("MyCnxString")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Types<Formula>()
        .Configure(c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name));

        modelBuilder.Types<OperandInt>()
        .Configure(c => c.ToTable(c.ClrType.Name));
    }

    public DbSet<Formula> Formula { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OperandInt> OperandValue { get; set; }

}
```

And my test program :

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");


        var migration = new TestEntity2.Migrations.Configuration();
        migration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        migration.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

        var migrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(migration);
        migrator.Update();


        using (ModelEntity db = new ModelEntity())
        {
            OperandInt opValue1 = new OperandInt() { Value = 3 };
            db.OperandValue.Add(opValue1);

            OperandInt opValue2 = new OperandInt() { Value = 4 };
            db.OperandValue.Add(opValue2);

            Formula formula = new Formula() { Operand1 = opValue1, Operand2 = opValue2, Operator = "*" };
            db.Formula.Add(formula);


            db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Ended !");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this program I obtain this error message :

**The relationship 'Formula_Operand1' does not match any relationship defined in the conceptual model.**

The problem is "Formula" does not find the Operand1 and Operand2 Ids relationShip due to the GenericType inheritance

Do you have any suggestions?

This a link to classDiagram :
http://imageshack.us/a/img443/1854/jl98.png

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check below mentioned links.@John explained about above issue is as below.

> EF does not support inheritance as you are attempting. It will work
>   with abstract classes, but non-virtual properties. Generic Inhertiance
>   is supported, but not from an abstract entity with a virtual property.
>   You can have an abstract entity, but need non-virtual properties.

For more info : [G+ Solution](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108190973756926786179/posts/eCJhME1S8Ze)

And : [Implementing Inheritance with the Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)